# Creating a forum with Laravel but having problems with Angular

Tags: php, html, angular, laravel, typescript

I'm creating a forum with users, posts and comments with Laravel and now I have to use Angular but I'm new to it so I have no Idea where to begin.

I've tried to return the json data from my laravel application (a user for instance), but I don't know to get them from Angular.

`public function index(){
  $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
  $user = User::find($user_id); return response()->json($user,201);
 }`

I'd be pleased if someone can help or recommend me something.

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In your angular project, you will have to create a service.ts file. The service may contain your API calls related to the user model.

```
//run the command
ng generate service user

//In your user.service.ts file 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...

export class UserService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    API_URL = 'http://yourLaravelApiProject/public/api';

    userDetails() {
        return this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL}/yourApiUrl`);
        //console.log()
    }
}
```

Do well to read more on services, interceptors. Or try out the Angular tutorial [Angular Tuorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)